# How to use a variable path in MySQL query in a Python script

Tags: python, mysql, sql, path

I am having trouble getting a variable path into a MySQL query in a python script. The path variable is either resolved with double backslashes or none at all.

This works:

```
 cursor.execute ("""load data local infile 'M:/Users/Jonathan/Dropbox/BCHS_3015/Spatial Data/Cartographic Data/USA/acs_data/Sequence_Number_and_Table_Number_Lookup.csv'
                into table Sequence_Table_Lookup
                fields terminated by ','enclosed by '"'
                lines terminated by '\r\n'
                ignore 1 lines
                (File_ID,Table_ID,Sequence_Number,Line_Number, Subject_Area)""");
```

This following returns the error:

```
_mysql_exceptions.InternalError: (22, "File 'M:UsersJonathanDropbox\x08chs_3015spatial datacartographic datausaacs_dataSequence_Number_and_Table_Number_Lookup.txt' not found (Errcode: 22)")

 cursor.execute ("""load data local infile '%s'
                into table Sequence_Table_Lookup
                fields terminated by ','enclosed by '"'
                lines terminated by '\r\n'
                ignore 1 lines
                (File_ID,Table_ID,Sequence_Number,Line_Number, Subject_Area)""" % filepath);
```

Removing the single quotes around %s yields

```
_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right 
syntax to use near 'M:\\Users\\Jonathan\\Dropbox\\bchs_3015\\spatial data\\cartographic data\\usa\\acs_data\\' at line 1")
```

I would appreciate any help in understanding how to insert a variable path into a MySQL query.

I am using PyDev in Eclipse on a windows machine. Python 2.7 and MySQLdb connector.

The full block of relevant code

```
conn = MySQLdb.connect (host = "localhost",
                           user = "user",
                           passwd = "pwd",
                           db = "gis_census_acs")
#finds census directory
dropbox = navigation.get_dropbox_home()
acs_data = os.path.join(dropbox,'bchs_3015','spatial data','cartographic data','usa','acs_data');

for filepath in navigation.get_filepaths(acs_data):
        filename = os.path.split(filepath)[1]
        if filename == 'Sequence_Number_and_Table_Number_Lookup.txt':
            print filepath;
            tablename = filename.split('.')[0].replace(' ','_')[0:64]
            cursor = conn.cursor()
            cursor.execute ('create table if not exists ' + tablename + """(
                    File_ID varchar(255),
                    Table_ID varchar(255),
                    Sequence_Number varchar(255),
                    Line_Number varchar(255),
                    Start_Position varchar(255),
                    Total_cells_in_Table varchar(255),
                    Total_Cells_in_Sequence varchar(255),
                    Table_title text,
                    Subject_Area text
                    )""");
            cursor.execute ("""load data local infile '%s'
                    into table Sequence_Table_Lookup
                    fields terminated by ','enclosed by '"'
                    lines terminated by '\r\n'
                    ignore 1 lines
                    (File_ID,Table_ID,Sequence_Number,Line_Number, Start_Position, 
                    Total_cells_in_Table, Total_Cells_in_Sequence, Table_title, Subject_Area)""" % filepath);
            print "Number of rows inserted: %d" % cursor.rowcount
            cursor.close()
        else:
            print "not the file"
conn.close ()
```

Comment: It's not a syntax error, the filepath you're entering is invalid.

Comment: What does the method `navigation.get_dropbox_home` returns?

Answer (score 0):

This file exists:

```
M:/Users/Jonathan/Dropbox/BCHS_3015/Spatial Data/Cartographic Data/USA/acs_data/Sequence_Number_and_Table_Number_Lookup.csv
```

As you expect, this strange one doesnt:

```
M:UsersJonathanDropbox\x08chs_3015spatial datacartographic datausaacs_dataSequence_Number_and_Table_Number_Lookup.txt
```

Seems like there's something wrong with your filepath. Try checking it out.

Comment: thanks @alKid. You are correct the path problematic. The first path above is hardcoded. the second is how the variable resolves. ' M:UsersJonathanDropbox ' should be 'code'M:Users\Jonathan\Dropbox\'code'. It is returned by the method  'code'navigation.get_dropbox_home'code'. The second segment 'code'x08chs_...Lookup.txt'code' is the path to the file. It is returned by 'code'navigation.get_filepath'code'. That method uses 'code'os.path.join'code' to create a list of paths in a directory. A print statement for 'code'filepath'code' within the loop works. The slashes break in the SQL.

Comment: thanks @alKid. You are correct the path is problematic. The first path above is hardcoded. the second is how the variable resolves. `M:UsersJonathanDropbox` should be `M:Users\Jonathan\Dropbox\`. It is returned by the method  `navigation.get_dropbox_home`. The second segment `x08chs_...Lookup.txt` is the path to the file. It is returned by `navigation.get_filepath`. That method uses `os.path.join` to create a list of paths in a directory. A print statement for `filepath` within the loop works. The slashes break in the SQL.